# Rotating object to face mouse pointer on mousemove

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I've got a mousemove cursor in my game which will make my object shoot towards my mouse cursor. I'd like my object to always rotate along to be in line with my mousecursor. How can i  convert the X and Y of where the cursor is to a degree angle to rotate my object to?

I hope my fiddle will make things a little clearer of to what i mean by rotating the player(Black block): http://jsfiddle.net/3nEUv/4/

Here's my mouseMove function now; Only making sure the cursor remains in it's bounding box

```
function mouseMove(e) {
    if (cursor) {
        if (e.rawX && e.rawY) {
            cursorBoundingBox(e.rawX, e.rawY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If SO hasn't come up with a solution before, I might try after I looked some things up. But I hope there's a better solution.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Basically you need to find the vector between the the point in the center of your box, and the point of the mouse cursor, then calculate the angle and convert it to degrees. Then just apply the angle via CSS:

```js
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
let boxBoundingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
let boxCenter= {
    x: boxBoundingRect.left + boxBoundingRect.width/2, 
    y: boxBoundingRect.top + boxBoundingRect.height/2
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    let angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - boxCenter.x, - (e.pageY - boxCenter.y) )*(180 / Math.PI);      
    box.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;  
})
```

**WAIT, WHAT?**

Ok, let's take this apart. This is what we have:

[image]

The vector AB goes between the center of the box and the mouse position. We went to calculate Θ (theta), which is the angle between the X axis and AB.

Imagine a line going down from B parallel to the Y axis until it touches the X axis. Using that line, AB and the X axis we get a triangle. That means we can use the Arctan function to calculate theta. More precisely, we use the convenience function of [Arctan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) which gives a positive angle when y>0 and negative angle when y<0.

atan2 returns the degrees in *radians*, and CSS works with *degrees*, so we convert between the two using `180/Math.PI`. (A radian is the measure of an angle that, when drawn a central angle of a circle, intercepts an arc whose length is equal to the length of the radius of the circle. - Taken from [here](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/radians/convert-degee-to-radians.php) )

One last caveat - Since in the browser the Y axis is inverted (meaning, the further down you go in the page, the higher the Y value gets), we had to flip the Y axis: We did so by adding a minus sign on the Y term:

`- (e.pageY - boxCenter[1])`

I hope this helps clear some things...

Here's an isolated [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4c039kn6/1/)

BTW, Your game is hard! :)

Comment: Easy games are for suckers!! :-p I'm gonna check it out. Could you perhaps specify some of the things you're doing in the code? I'm not really a math genius so :D

Comment: Sure, I'll include some graphic illustrating the calculation. It's really simple geometry :)

Comment: I guess i'm doing something wrong, but this isn't the way it rotated in your example; What am i doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/6TqjC/ (Mousemove is on 498)

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that helps clear up things. If not, please let me know and I'll have a look a bit later!

Comment: I think i somewhat get it. Nonetheless i can't get it to work properly. I might have the wrong data from my mouse event or something..? See my comment 46 minutes ago.

Comment: @CaptainCarl Your box center calculation is incorrect.  Change the `pos/size` to a `pos-size`, i.e. `[player.sprite.x/(player.sprite.width/2), player.sprite.y/(player.sprite.height/2)];` to `[player.sprite.x-(player.sprite.width/2), player.sprite.y-(player.sprite.height/2)];`

Comment: That's just a dumb mistake. Thanks alot @Deestan

Comment: @Deestan you beat me to the punch :D Glad it worked out for you Carl

Comment: I would just like to point out for anybody coming to this post like I did. that Math.atan2() takes Y as the first number and X as the second number. Here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

Comment: I need angle to be between 0 and 360, not -180 and 180. Is there a better way to do it other than
`angle = parseInt(angle < 0 ? 360 + angle : angle );` ? For example in the Math.atan2 formula?

Comment: @DrorBar if you add 180 to the -180 to 180 range you get 0 to 360 range ...

Comment: Calculation is incorrect, rotate does NOT work as expected. angle calculation should be as following;
 let angle = Math.atan2((e.pageY - top - boxCenter.y), e.pageX - left - boxCenter.x) * (180 / Math.PI);

Answer (score 4):

I have create a rotation script for the every html element with passing angle of rotation.

**Hope it will help**

```
function MouseRotate(e, elt) {
  var offset = elt.offset();
  var center_x = (offset.left) + (elt.width() / 2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + (elt.height() / 2);
  var mouse_x = e.pageX;
  var mouse_y = e.pageY;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
  $(elt).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  $(elt).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  $(elt).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  $(elt).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#'+tagVal).mousedown(function(e) {
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2,$('#'+tagVal));
    });
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
  });
});
```

Comment: I Have tried this code in my project and working fine, But I need to get the value of a degree from 0-360, but I can't get it from the above formula. can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

This radians to degrees conversion worked for me:

```
const angleRadians = Math.atan2(positionUnits.x - this.rotationPivotPoint.x, -(positionUnits.y - this.rotationPivotPoint.y));
const angleDegrees = angleRadians * (180 / Math.PI);
const angle = -(90 - angleDegrees);
```