# One finger rotation in React Native

Tags: react-native, rotation, image-rotation

i'm wondering if in in React Native there's the possibility to rotate an image 360 degrees with one finger. 
Do you think i need to make my custom implementation?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You could create a component and use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html to rotate the image depending on your pull range

Comment: Could you make an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: You should try something yourself first. Let other people know you're making an effort. If you're only here to find working code, you should hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Other than that, I think it's possible, something like this should point you in the right direction in terms of mathematical functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653801/rotating-object-to-face-mouse-pointer-on-mousemove