# Animating SVG: Move shape in direction of mouse/rotate around fixed point?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg.js, onmousemove

After looking through similar questions posted to the forum and not finding something that helped me solve my own problem, I'm posting it.

I'm using [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/) to generate SVG shapes in a web document. I'd like one of those shapes to ”follow” the mouse/cursor.

By that I mean: The shape has a fixed position/anchor point (at its original center) and it can only move a limited distance (let's say 50px) away from this fixed point. 
I want the shape to move in the direction of the cursor, whenever the cursor moves, but never further than a defined distance away from its orignal position. I'm attaching a short animation to illustrate my description:

[image]

If the cursor were to disappear, the shape would snap back to its original center.

I know my way around Javascript, HTML and CSS. This type of element-manipulation is new to me and the math is giving my quite the headache, any help would be great.

It looks like I need the shape to basically rotate around its original center, with an angle relative to the cursor? I'm really unsure how to solve this. I have tried using a method to calculate the angle [described in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653801/rotating-object-to-face-mouse-pointer-on-mousemove) My shape moves, but not as intended:

```js
// init
var draw = SVG().addTo('body')

// draw 
window.shape = draw.circle(25, 25).stroke({
  color: '#000',
  width: 2.5
}).fill("#fff");
shape.attr("id", "circle1");
shape.move(50, 50)


// move
var circle = $("#circle1");
var dist = 10;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  // angle
  var circleCenter = [circle.offset().left + circle.width() / 2, circle.offset().top + circle.height() / 2];
  var angle = Math.atan2(e.clientX - circleCenter[0], -(e.clientY - circleCenter[1])) * (180 / Math.PI);

  var x = Math.sin(angle) * dist;
  var y = (Math.cos(angle) * dist) * -1;

  shape.animate().dmove(x, y);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.16/svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: It does not matter to me whether the solution depends on jQuery or not (ideally it doesn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more fiddling around with some solutions to calculating angles and distances, I found the answer.

I'm using a fixed reference point to calculate the angle of the direct line between the center of the shape and the cursor. Then I move the shape relative to this reference point and by a given amount:

```js
// Init canvas
var draw = SVG().addTo('body')

// Draw reference/anchor
var shape_marker_center = draw.circle(3,3).fill("#f00").move(150, 150);;
var grafikCenter = [shape_marker_center.attr("cx"), shape_marker_center.attr("cy")]

// Draw shapes
var shape = draw.circle(25, 25).stroke({color: '#000', width: 2.5 }).fill("none");
shape.attr("id", "circle1").attr({cx: grafikCenter[0], cy:grafikCenter[1]})
var shape2 = draw.circle(50, 50).stroke({color: '#000', width: 2.5 }).fill("none");
shape2.attr("id", "circle2").attr({cx: grafikCenter[0], cy:grafikCenter[1]})
var shape3 = draw.circle(75, 75).stroke({color: '#000', width: 2.5 }).fill("none");
shape3.attr("id", "circle3").attr({cx: grafikCenter[0], cy:grafikCenter[1]})

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var pointA = [shape_marker_center.attr("cx"), shape_marker_center.attr("cy")];
  var pointB = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
  var angle = Math.atan2(pointB[1] - pointA[1], pointB[0] - pointA[0]) * 180 / Math.PI ;
  //
  var distance_x_1 = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180) * 16;
  var distance_y_1 = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * 16;
  var distance_x_2 = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180) * 8;
  var distance_y_2 = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * 8;
  //
  shape.center((grafikCenter[0] + distance_x_1), (grafikCenter[1] + distance_y_1));
  shape2.center((grafikCenter[0] + (distance_x_2) ), (grafikCenter[1] + (distance_y_2)));
})
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.16/svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```